# menubar's sliding effect and tabs not appear

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, menubar, jquery-ui-menubar

I want when pointing from one menu to another menu, the menu looked like a sliding board. 
i can show that after downloaded at apycom.com,
beside that, i have a jquery-ui tabs in `input.php`.
the problem comes after i have included that menubar.
menubar's sliding effect not show and also the tabs..
why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, this is not possible in pure CSS. However, it's possible with the addition of javascript. Check out the "accordion" effect on google.

[jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) has a nice implementation.